# How do I restart SSH service on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, command-line, sudo, restart

Installed freshly Ubuntu Server 16.04 LTS including OpenSSH server. I now want to restart the ssh server by `sudo restart ssh` but then I get:

> sudo: restart: command not found

Is `restart` not a default command or program or script, and how do I get it?